# Highcharts - set maximum range for yAxis but keep axis dynamic within that range

Tags: jquery, highcharts

First of all, apologies for the post title, but I failed to come up with a better one to describe my problem.

Is there a way in highcharts to set the maximum value for the yAxis to, say, 1000 (i.e. via `max: 1000`) but keep it dynamic if the maximum values are lower than the set maximum? As an example, let's say we have two datasets.

The first one ranges between 0 and 1500. Here any data >1000 should not be displayed. Setting `yAxis: { max: 1000 }` does the trick.

Now we update the data series with the second data set which ranges between 0 and 48. Now `max: 1000` causes the line to virtually hug the x-axis. So here it would be best if Highcharts dynamically adjusts the yAxis to range from 0-50.

Here's a fiddle to illustrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/PanicJ/s7fZu/1/

P.S.
Just noticed the [`minRange`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.minRange) setting in Highcharts. Now, why isn't there a `maxRange` equivalent? Or is there?

Comment: There is no such option like `maxRange`, you can create request [here](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that there is no `maxRange` equivalent (feature request, Torstein?) so that the axis maximum has to be determined before Highcharts is called. Building upon Sanath's suggestion a solution would be this:

```
$(function () {
   var setA = [29.9, 11.5, 36.4, 19.2, 4.0, 46.0, 48.2, 15.2, 16.4, 4.1, 5.6, 44.4];
   var setB = [129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 248.5, 316.4, 694.1, 795.6, 954.4, 1029.9, 1171.5, 1506.4];
   var data = Math.random() < 0.5 ? setA : setB;
   var height=Math.max.apply(Math, data);
   if(height > 1000){ height = 1000; }

   $('#container').highcharts({
       chart: {
           marginRight: 80 // like left
       },
       xAxis: {
           categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
       },
       yAxis: [{
           lineWidth: 1,
           max: height,
           min: 0,
           title: { text: 'yAxis' }
       }],
       series: [{
           data: data
       }]
   });
});
```

As working example: http://jsfiddle.net/PanicJ/H2pyC/8/

Answer (score 4):

please use setExtremes to define a range. The JSfiddle has been updated.

```
 $('#button').click(function () {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts(

    );
    if ($(this).hasClass('big')) {
        $(this).removeClass('big');
        chart.series[0].setData([29.9, 11.5, 36.4, 19.2, 4.0, 46.0, 48.2, 15.2, 16.4, 4.1, 5.6, 44.4]);
        //chart.setSize(null,100,true);
        chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(0,50);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('big');
        chart.series[0].setData([129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 248.5, 316.4, 694.1, 795.6, 954.4, 1029.9, 1171.5, 1506.4]);
        //chart.setSize(null,1600,true);
        chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(0,1600);
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: then you have to calculate yAxis max value based on the available set of values and populate 




       yAxis: [{
            lineWidth: 1,
            max: CALCULATED_MAXVALUE,

Comment: Okay, thanks. So that means there is no `maxRange` equivalent in Highcharts, huh?

Comment: Well, your answer as it is published here does not quite hit the nail on the head (requires event to rescale axis). Also, the latest revision of the jsfiddle you refer to (http://jsfiddle.net/H2pyC/6/) does not work (erroneous determination of selected data set). And it would also help others if you could post jsfiddle links somewhere. So I feel reluctant to accept your answer as it stands... but I have no problems to accept a corrected version of your question.

Comment: if(height > 1000) can be removed, it helps to properly display when large chart is enabled

updated my jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/H2pyC/6/

Answer (score 2):

Since Highcharts 4.0 we can use [`yAxis.ceiling`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.ceiling) and [`yAxis.floor`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.floor), [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f0fpzd4c/).

```
Highcharts.chart('container1', {
  yAxis: {
    floor: 0,
    ceiling: 100
  },
  series: [{
    data: [-10, 1, 0, 2, 3, 5, 8, 5, 15, 14, 25, 154]
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s7fZu/39/)

```
$(function() {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            marginRight: 80 // like left
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: [{
            lineWidth: 1,
            max: 1000,
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Primary Axis'
            }
        }, {
            lineWidth: 1,
            opposite: true,
            title: {
                text: 'Secondary Axis'
            }
        }],
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 11.5, 36.4, 19.2, 4.0, 46.0, 48.2, 15.2, 16.4, 4.1, 5.6, 44.4]
        }]
    });
    $('#button').click(function() {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        if ($(this).hasClass('big')) {
            $(this).removeClass('big');
            chart.series[0].setData([29.9, 11.5, 36.4, 19.2, 4.0, 46.0, 48.2, 15.2, 16.4, 4.1, 5.6, 44.4]);
            chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(0, 50);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('big');
            chart.series[0].setData([129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 248.5, 316.4, 694.1, 795.6, 954.4, 1029.9, 1171.5, 1506.4]);
            chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(0, 1600);
        }
    });
});
```

This solution should work for you, you just need to set yAxis extremes for the chart, if you know the maximum data range for each series it would be easy, otherwise you need to calculate the maximum value for each series.